# Extract DOCX comments and reference text with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx, pywin32

Is there a way to extract the comment content and the referenced text without using COM? I provided a working solution below, but looking to do this without COM.

The solution below was provided by [Extract DOCX Comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47390928/extract-docx-comments)

```
word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
word.Visible = False 

comments = []
doc = word.Documents.Open(report_path)
doc.Activate()
active_doc = word.ActiveDocument
for c in active_doc.Comments: 
        if c.Ancestor is None:
            comments.append([c.Scope.Text, c.Range.Text])
doc.Close()
```